# How to run only shopify backend app locally

Tags: node.js, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-api-node

I've created a shopify app using CLI, now I found it has a dedicated frontend setup yet no backend. What is the best approach.

Should I create a embedded backend with shopify app itself, if so how can I run the app locally (without running the frontend)
Or, I should create a dedicated backend app hosted in other cloud platform so that shopify frontend app can call endpoints?

Can anyone please suggest the best way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which command did you use? If you followed the tutorial it has a frontend and a backend.

Comment: This worked. My bad. I didn't notice.